# CLLocationManager is alive even when not needed

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager

I have a mapping functionality in my app. It belongs to one of the Tab Bar controller tabs.

The problem I have is that the app is asking for location permissions right after launch. 
I dont want to bother the user with location related questions until he actually goes to that map part of the app.

If I understand properly, location manager should not bother to ask for that until I instantiate it. Also, as soon as the user leaves that map part of the app, either by selecting other tabs or by pressing home button..I nil the location manager.

Why is it then asking for that so soon? My question is whether there is some special rule in this particular case...or it is caused by my flawed app design?

Comment: Put a break point on the line where you instantiate CLLocationManager and call startUpdatingLocation. It should not ask for permission until after you hit the breakpoint.

Comment: I dont see any issue with this question. Would the -1er bother to explain his objections? Instead just "stealing" my hardly earned points?

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with the "flowed app design" one. You don't showed any code, so it's hard to say, but UITabBarController instantiates all its View Controllers at once, so your CCLocation class is probably being initialized with your TabBar.

What you could do is: initialize your CCLocation stuff only on the `-viewWillAppear` method on the View Controller that you actually use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like this.

## h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface LocationController : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLLocation *currentLocation;
} 

+ (LocationController *)sharedInstance;
- (void)start;
- (void)stop;

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *currentLocation;

@end
```

## m:

```
#import "LocationController.h"

@implementation LocationController

static LocationController *sharedInstance;

+ (LocationController *)sharedInstance {
    static LocationController *sharedClient;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedClient = [[LocationController alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedClient;
}

-(id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        currentLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] init];
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        [self start];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)start {
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)stop {
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *loc = [locations lastObject];

    if ( abs([loc.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate: [NSDate date]]) < 120) {
        self.currentLocation = loc;
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}

@end
```

Then whenever you need to locate you can do the following:

```
[[LocationController sharedInstance] start];
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you instantiating the `CLLocationManager`? While all the view controllers are instantiated when the tab bar controller is instantiated, their respective views are not created until you go to the relevant tab. So, if you're instantiating your `CLLocationManager` in one of the controller's `init` methods, then that location manager will be created when the controllers are (i.e. when the tab bar controller is instantiated). If you have the instantiation of the location manager in `viewDidLoad`, though, it shouldn't be instantiated until you click on the appropriate tab.